# Regular expression for e-mail:password (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, email, passwords

*I am not too unfamiliar with regexes, but I just figured I'm much better at reading and understanding them than at writing them myself. Can't get this to work.*

**E-mail:password**

Basically, it needs to verify an e-mail address and a password of any lengths, separated by a colon with or without spaces around it.

Passwords can include absolutely any character, colons included. E-mails cannot include colons, but as far as I'm aware they really can't anyways.

True:

- Em@il.com:password
- Em@il.com : p@55w:rd
- Em@il.co.uk :p@$ worD
- Em@il.com:  password

False:

- Nomail.com:password
- Nom@ailcom: password
- Nomail:password
- E:m@il.com:password

Thanks!

---

Many thanks to F.J! With his help along with the e-mail verification from [Markus Sipilä](http://www.markussipila.info/pub/emailvalidator.php?action=validate) I usually use, this is what it became:

```
^[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,})[ ]?:.*$
```

Of course, when adding F.J's bit of code ([ ]?:.*) to the end of any e-mail verifying string, keep in mind you might have to get rid of end-of-line archors. Adding the "optional" part to it, meaning it could either be left empty (^$) or (|) follow the string, makes:

```
(^$|^[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,})[ ]?:.*$)
```

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I understand, but I tried so much that I ended with one bit of absolute gibberish, and to start all over showing all incorrect tries would not help much, I suppose, especially not when coming across someone who knows how regular expressions are written. All I need is the correct regex. What I tried so far did not let any tries through (form submission to PHP).

Comment: @Downvoter, I know I did not show research efforts (apart from the fact I searched the hell out of the site and internets and found no one has asked this question before). But I did follow all the rules and tips at posting a question and I'm sure showing all failures was not part of that. I'm pretty sure the question couldn't be more clear, so please elaborate.

Comment: I understand that you tried a lot, but give us something to go off of.  We're not going to write the code for you, but we will help you along.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when asking any question on here in the future.. if I dare. This is the first and only question I have asked here, and I followed all the guidelines thoroughly and have looked around at other questions to see if I was doing it right. I am sorry I did not know or see any indications of this particular rule, and to get downvoted for that I find a bit upsetting and scary as a newcomer. I am sure the post is very clear, and now very helpful too. Thanks again to F.J, and thank you for your understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry if we scared you.  We don't want to scare you away.  I try to be as helpful as possible, while helping you help yourself.  We just can't start from zero.  Give us a starting point and we can go from there.  When you say "All I need is the correct regex", you're underestimating what that may involve.  A regex is basically a small program, with all the same needs and requirements as a program.  It has to be well-defined what the behavior is going to be, and no regex is one-size-fits-all any more than a program is one-size-fits-all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take [a good regex to match an email](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), and then add `[ ]?:.*` to the end of it (square brackets are not necessary, but make it a little easier to see there is a single space there).

Comment: Thanks so much! I was thinking and adding waaaay too much. Accepted yours as the answer. I have added to final results to the top post/question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that email addresses cannot contain colons then it is as simple as:

```
$string = 'Em@il.com:p@55w:rd';

$colon = strpos($string, ':');
$email = substr($string, 0, $colon);
$passw = substr($string, $colon + 1);

if ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die('Invalid email address');
}
if (strlen($passw) < 8) { // For example
    die('Invalid password');
}
```

Validating email addresses using regular expressions is pretty much impossible. The most advanced regexes for validating email addresses may do the job, most of the time, but they are monstrosities that cannot be maintained or even understood by a living thing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and try, but sometimes one does not have a choice and needs an answer to the exact question, in my case a regex. In my case, I can only use your code in one of the two instances I need it for. For instances, some message board and other systems allow just regexes to verify form fields, and then any non-regex code like yours would not help.